# Use h5py `family` and `mpio` drivers simultaneously

Tags: python, mpi, hdf5, h5py

I would like to use both the `family` and `mpio` [drivers](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html#file-drivers) in h5py to do parallel reads of a family of files.

1. Is this even possible?
2. How do you specify the arguments? Using `family` but setting the `comm` argument doesn't work, and vice versa; using a family string (e.g. "`file.%d.h5`") but using `mpio`.
3. Have tried providing driver arguments as a list, but this is not recognised.

Comment: As far as I know, HDF5 can only use one driver for a given file handle.

Comment: yeah, seems it. However, it turns out you don't need the family driver to do parallel reads, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251839/is-it-possible-to-do-parallel-reads-on-one-h5py-file-using-multiprocessing